# Need a script to create folders based on file names, and auto move files

Tags: loops, batch-file

I need a batch file (for Windows) that I can run that will take a (very) large number of files, and place them in their own folders.

The source directory has a structure as follows:

```
\\Movies\Movie1.mkv
\\Movies\Movie1.idx
\\Movies\Movie1.sub
\\Movies\Movie1.jpg
\\Movies\Movie1.mkv_sheet.jpg

\\Movies\Movie2.mkv
\\Movies\Movie2.idx
\\Movies\Movie2.sub

\\Movies\Movie3.mkv
\\Movies\Movie3.idx
\\Movies\Movie3.sub
```

I need it to create a folder based on the mkv file name, and then move Movie*.* into that folder so it looks like this:

```
\\Movies\Movie1\Movie1.mkv
\\Movies\Movie1\Movie1.idx
\\Movies\Movie1\Movie1.sub
\\Movies\Movie1\Movie1.jpg
\\Movies\Movie1\Movie1.mkv_sheet.jpg

\\Movies\Movie2\Movie2.mkv
\\Movies\Movie2\Movie2.idx
\\Movies\Movie2\Movie2.sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited to use path specified in comment*

```
@echo off
pushd D:\Video
for %%F in (*.mkv) do (
  2>nul md "%%~nF"
  >nul move /y "%%~nF*.*" "%%~nF"
)
popd
```

Comment: Maybe change the `*.txt` to something appropriate to the question ;) – `*` should probably do the job.

Comment: @Joey - Oops! Thanks, I'll fix that.

Comment: Ok, I changed the "\\Movies" to "D:\Video", copied to a .bat file, and ran it, and it's giving me "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: @Dizzy49 - I can't imagine what is not working. I've tested on Windows 7 and it works fine for me. It also should work on prior Windows versions to at least XP.

Comment: I have Windows 7.  Am I missing something obvious?  I just need to copy/past it into a .bat file, and then run it, correct?  I don't need to run it a certain way, using a certain program or anything?

Comment: @Dizzy49 - It should be just that simple. I've modified the code to use "D:\Video". Your code should look exactly like above.

Comment: Ok, first off, I'm stupid.  I thought I turned off another program that polls that folder, so it moved them already (eyeroll).  Secondly, it moved everything (movie.mkv, movie.jpg, but it missed movie-fanart.jpg).  I changed `>nul move /y "%%~nF.*" "%%~nF"` to `>nul move /y "%%~nF*.*" "%%~nF"` to correct that.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for the same thing on Linux / MacOS, this should do the job:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Specify the source folder
source_folder="/path/to/source/folder"

# Check if the source folder exists
if [ ! -d "$source_folder" ]; then
  echo "Source folder does not exist."
  exit 1
fi

# Move to the source folder
cd "$source_folder" || exit 1

# Iterate through each file in the source folder
for file in *; do
  # Check if it's a file, not a directory
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    # Extract the file name without extension
    file_name="${file%.*}"
    
    # Create a new folder with a unique identifier
    folder_name="$file_name"
    mkdir -p "$folder_name"
    
    # Move the file into the new folder
    mv "$file" "$folder_name/"
    
    echo "Moved $file to $folder_name/"
  fi
done

echo "Organizing files complete."
```

Make sure you change your `source_folder="/path/to/source/folder"` at the top of the file to the folder you wish to operate on. I've tested this on MacOS with the folder pointing to a mounted network volume on a NAS and it works no problem.

On MacOS, if you mount a network folder you can find the path under the /Volumes folder.