# Batch: create a folder based on part of filename and then copy the file into it

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a folder with a bunch of .avi and .wav files. Their names are as follows:

`{NameX}_{DateX}`

I need an expression that creates folders called `{Name1}`, `{Name2}`, etc, and then copies the respective files into those folders.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry, here's what I tried so far.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*.avi"'
 ) DO (  
 MD %%a
 MOVE "%%a %%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

It didn't work though, and I don't know why.

Here's a concrete filename, I think it might help.

```
hl2_2014_12_26_04_05_12_268.avi
```

Comment: I'm a beginner in batch as I never felt the need to use it, but I messed about with it a bit with the help of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992530/batch-create-folders-based-on-part-of-file-name-and-move-files-into-that-folder) I cobbled together (more like slightly edited) this:

`@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*.avi"'
 ) DO (  
 MD %%a
 MOVE "%%a %%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF`

Comment: @TiagoVeloso - Edit your question and include this code as a starting point for help.

Comment: I did it now; I didn't notice the comments didn't keep formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *really* close.

You are just missing a delimiter in your `FOR` statement (if you omit the `delims` parameter it will use a space as the default) to break the name apart by an underscore. Then you need to "reassemble" the file name back in your `MOVE` statement by combining the tokens.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%

REM Use the underscore _ as a delimiter.
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*.avi"') DO (
    REM Name the folder based on what is before the first token.
    MD %%a
    REM To get the full filename, concatenate the tokens back together.
    MOVE "%%a_%%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I am attempting to do the same thing, but with spaces in the files for example: Key Bing Information_2019-01-01.csv.  Any idea how I can modify this script?